# How can I pause and resume stream processing periodically(every 5 minutes) using Kafka Streams and Spring Kafka Streams?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I'm newbie in kafka streams. I need to create kafka streams dynamically from config files, which contain source and destination topic names.
Is it possible to restart and stop Kafka streams? My goal is transferring messages from one topic to another periodically using kafka streams.
I used spring cron job and tried closing and opening stream but I can't start it again when I close a stream. I got this error --> The client is either already started or already stopped, cannot re-start. I'm writing the code in java

```
         +--------------+
               +<----- | Created (0)  |
               |       +-----+--------+
               |             |
               |             v
               |       +----+--+------+
               |       | Re-          |
               +<----- | Balancing (1)| -------->+
               |       +-----+-+------+          |
               |             | ^                 |
               |             v |                 |
               |       +--------------+          v
               |       | Running (2)  | -------->+
               |       +------+-------+          |
               |              |                  |
               |              v                  |
               |       +------+-------+     +----+-------+
               +-----> | Pending      |<--- | Error (5)  |
                       | Shutdown (3) |     +------------+
                       +------+-------+
                              |
                              v
                       +------+-------+
                       | Not          |
                       | Running (4)  |
                       +--------------+
```

Comment: Please show the relevant part of your code and the exact error message. The question is too vague to be answered.

Comment: Actually I want to pause and resume streams periodically. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You posted a diagram of the streams thread states, and you say "I got this error" without showing the error. Could you please edit your question to just reflect "I want to pause and resume streams periodically"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two methods `pause` and `resume` on the `KafkaStreams` class that you can use to pause and resume processing.

https://kafka.apache.org/33/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/KafkaStreams.html#pause--
https://kafka.apache.org/33/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/KafkaStreams.html#resume--

You could use the `scheduleAtFixedRate` method of the `java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService` to schedule pausing and resuming every 5 minutes.

Comment: Thanks @Lucas Brutschy. Pause and resume methods worked.

Answer (score 0):

if you use Spring Cloud Stream -
you can hook into BindingsLifecycleController

see https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html

the other option is to expose the controls via Actuator endPoints and call it
(more info also in the same link)